# Java, String index out of bounds in while loop

Tags: string, while-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(romanToInt("DCXXI"));
    }

    public static int romanToInt(String s) {
        int ln = s.length()-1;
        int ans = 0;   
        int i=0;

        while (i <=ln){
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'M'){
                ans += 1000;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'D'){
                ans += 500;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'C' && s.charAt(i+1)=='D'){
                    ans += 400;
                    i=i+1;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'C' && s.charAt(i+1)=='M'){
                    ans += 900;
                    i=i+1;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'C'){
                    ans += 100;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'L'){
                ans += 50;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'X' && s.charAt(i+1)=='L'){
                    ans += 40;
                    i=i+1;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'X' && s.charAt(i+1)=='C'){
                    ans += 90;
                    i=i+1;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'X'){
                    ans += 10;
            }else if (s.charAt(i) == 'V'){
                ans += 5;
            }else if (s.charAt(i)=='I' && s.charAt(i+1)=='V'){
                    ans += 4;
                    i=i+1;
            }else if (s.charAt(i)=='I' && s.charAt(i+1)=='X'){
                    ans += 9;
                    i=i+1;
            }else if (s.charAt(i)=='I'){
                    ans += 1;
            }
            i++;
            System.out.printf("Current sum is: %s and current pointer i is: %s \n",ans, i);
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

I keep getting error message

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   5

But I couldn't find where I did it wrong. Can someone help me?
Output:
This is D
Current sum is: 500 and current pointer i is: 1 
This is C
Current sum is: 600 and current pointer i is: 2 
This is X
Current sum is: 610 and current pointer i is: 3 
This is X
Current sum is: 620 and current pointer i is: 4 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Solution.romanToInt(Solution.java:65)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:9)

Comment: That's sure a lot of conditional logic to take in at a glance.  Its' not even clear what you're trying to accomplish. May I suggest breaking the problem down into into small steps and making sure each of them work.

Comment: use some kind of sentinel to mark the end of string, like a space, in order to avoid index checks, the ones you missed.

Comment: Thank you, guys, I use a lot of if-else statements because I've just started learning Java. Not sure where went wrong.

Comment: Never mind, I found it, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You set

```
int ln = s.length()-1;
```

and use

```
while (i <=ln){....}
```

then get

```
s.charAt(i+1)
```

so it is possibly i+1 >= s.length();

then s.charAt(i+1) will throw Exception

Comment: I also notice this but those s.charAt(i+1) are evaluated only when the following combinations occured, such as IV, IX, XL, XC, CD and CM. However, I still couldn't find the error.

Comment: the Error seem to appear on this line: if (s.charAt(i+1)=='I' && s.charAt(i+1)=='V') . and that line of code make no sense

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed an error, but it still throws an exception after I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

These two "else if" cases caused the exception:

```
        }else if (s.charAt(i+1)=='I' && s.charAt(i+1)=='V'){
         ....
        }else if (s.charAt(i+1)=='I' && s.charAt(i+1)=='X'){
         ....
```

Comment: I don't understand, the input I gave is DCXXI so it passes these two conditions, doesn't it?

Comment: sorry I meant these 2:
            }else if (s.charAt(i+1)=='I' && s.charAt(i+1)=='V'){

            }else if (s.charAt(i+1)=='I' && s.charAt(i+1)=='X'){

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it, but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you are at the last character of the string provided, you are testing, sometimes, string.charAt(i+1) that causes your IndexOutofBound exceptions.